# Pylance: Argument of type "int" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "Literal[24, 48]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pylance

```
from typing import Literal

def predict(window: Literal[24, 48]):
    pass

for window in [24, 48]:
    predict(window=window)
```

Let's say I have the above code. I'm trying to type annotate my code. However Pylance says it's incorrect:

> Argument of type "int" cannot be assigned to parameter "prediction_range" of type "Literal[24, 48, 168]" in function "predictor"
> Type "int" cannot be assigned to type "Literal[24, 48]"
> "int" cannot be assigned to type "Literal[24]"
> "int" cannot be assigned to type "Literal[48]"

I don't understand why the int 24 cannot be assigned to Literal int with the same value. What is the correct way to annotate this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[24, 48]` is deduced as `list[int]`. The information about specific values is lost.

If you want to specify a different type, you can:

```
from typing import Literal

def predict(window: Literal[24, 48]):
    pass

windows: list[Literal[24, 48]] = [24, 48]

for window in windows:
    predict(window=window)
```